# Web-browser needs again username and password

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, browser

While a web page -which needs login- is opened in my browser,
if I close browser and re-open, I have to write username password again.

But, sometimes when I close browser and re-open for the same page, it isn't needed username and password again?

Is it about Session, Cookie? If yes, why are there different conditions?
What do you think?

Comment: Could it be that your session times out, or it is totally random?

Comment: When I open the web page from another computer, there is no problem like this. When I re-open, it is not needed username and password. But from my computer, it is needed username and password generally.

Answer (score 0):

Gokturk

Its depend on which they session state management technique are used. basically there are 3 state management can used in asp.net

[Asp.Net state management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

i think webpage using Cookies with some Expiry period. if its session then when u close the 
browser then session will be cleared. (InProc Mode).

Cookie will expire for mentioned period, if u able to relogin after browser closed then the cookie is checked for your credentials.

for the different condition following the reasons will make point of it

1. if u cleared your browser data (sessions, cookies, etc)
2. u may clicked rememberd password, which would stored in Browser cache.

Comment: no it would not stored in Browser Cache via clicking remembered password.

Answer (score 0):

So it definitely seems the web site only allows session-based, non-persistant cookies.  My guess (as I've seen this on my system as well), the browser is closed, but the process hasn't died off.  When you open a "new" browser, it's picking up the existing process with all of the session information still valid.  To confirm this, each you close the browser, check Task Manager to ensure iexplore.exe, chrome.exe or firefox.exe are completely missing before starting a new session.

Comment: when you have seen this on your system. whenever you want to open it, is it needed username and password? I think in your case, it isn't needed username and password anytime?